# Two Routers, One Subnet

Tags: router, ip, subnet

I have two Routers and would like one subnet instead of 2, I am using services like upnp for video streaming and the second subnet of router 2 fails to discover it on certain devices.

The setup is as follows -

Router 1 - Main Router + Internet Access (192.168.0.1)

Router 2 - In my bedroom, Connected to Router 1 via Powerline adapters (192.168.0.2)

I have done the obvious and disabled DHCP on the second router and as soon as I do that I no longer get given an IP at all and cannot connect to Router 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The second router should not be a router. You need a bridge, e.g. a WAP. Some consumer-grade routers can be configured as a bridge. You need to disable DHCP, the firewall, NAT, etc. Your router may have a simple setting for bridge mode, or you may be able to manually disable all the router and firewall features. It may also be that your router cannot be configured this way.

Routers route packets between networks, so routers must have different networks on each router interface. A bridge, like a switch or WAP, switches frames on the same network, so all the bridge interfaces must be in the same network.

Comment: +1 : Ron's absolutely right.  Note that a "subnet" is just a network that may be smaller than another type of network.  So in his second paragraph, you could replace the word "network" with "subnet" if that's easier for you.  Common simple DHCP cannot cross subnets (using "DHC(P) Relay" can, and that's part of the official DHCP standard, but isn't the standard DHCP communications that are usually used), but if you tell your router to act as a bridge (forward Layer 2 e.g. Ethernet/WiFi traffic, instead of Layer 3 traffic like IP), you should find that stops breaking DHCP.

Comment: Ever since CIDR, the term subnet is really more of a verb instead of a noun: _Subnet a network (prefix) into smaller networks (prefixes)._ When there were fixed network sizes, it was also a noun. People still use it in the old way, just like many people can't get over network classes, which really no longer exist.

Comment: If subnet is no longer a noun, what word would you replace "subnet" with in the following sentence?  192.168.16.24/30 is a subnet of 192.168.16/28.  See, my definitions have no problem with that, because my definition of the verb subnet is to take a larger network, and identify multiple (2 or more) distinct (smaller) subnets out of it.  The word remains both a noun and a verb, very much like how an object cracking means making cracks, and quite like insult, bend, block, box/crate, comb, cook, copy, file, harness, & [numerous others](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/nounandverb.shtml)

Comment: I said it is _more_ of a verb than than a noun. The original noun version of subnet was a network that is smaller than the classful network size. In modern terminology `192.168.16.24/30` is a network on its own. You may have subnetted it from `192.168.16/28`, and you could refer to it that way if you are clear about the network from which it came, but I don't think the OP was referring to a network on the second router that was derived from the network on the first router. Those are probably two independent networks that were not subnetted from anything else.

Comment: "you could refer to it that way..." -- okay, that's exactly what I did. "... if you are clear about the network from which it came". Since you refer to the pre-CIDR history, surely you're sufficiently familiar to instantly identify the network from which it came.  I usually refer to the smaller networks within 192.168/16 as subnets, because I do think of them as my privately-controlled sections of the larger 192.168/16 network which was publicly declared to allow me (& anyone) to privately use (RFCs 1597 / 5735, ideally [IETF BCP5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp5), most famously RFC 1918)

Comment: ha ha... my first comment, which starts off by saying "+1 : Ron's absolutely right", currently has more up-votes than Ron's answer (which currently has just one up-vote: mine).  I'm not meaning to laugh at Ron, but at the situation.  Why does a person agree with me that Ron's absolutely right, but then not up-vote Ron's answer?  (I'm guessing Ron might have been one of the people who up-voted my comment, since it does compliment his answer.  Then, Ron can't up-vote his own answer.  So that makes sense, but that doesn't account for the other voter. I can't up-vote my own comment, so wasn't me.)

Comment: That thinking about subnets is a little convoluted. Originally, a subnet in the `192.168.0.0/16` range was only any prefix longer than `/24` because that range is in the old Class C range. My point is that a lot of people use the term subnet and network interchangeably, but, today, the terms are really network or prefix unless you specifically need to point out that it derived from a different network. Theoretically, all networks are subnets of `0.0.0.0/0`, but that is not a good use of the term.

Comment: By the way, It wasn't me that up voted anything here. I often see a disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase @ron-maupin in a more howto style:

For most simple routers that allow you to, disable DHCP (the simplest can't). In addition to disabling DHCP on Router2, just do not use Router2's WAN port, not for the Powerline, and not for PCs. Use any LAN ports.

With this combo, the router work like a switch/WAP.

Comment: Downvoting: Answer was much less clear than what was re-phrased.  This answer tried to provide some typical steps for configuring, which may be a useful addition to this answer.  But currently it seems very unreadable.  Use the preview window before submitting, and consider typing "<BR>" as part of the answer (to create new lines) so this is much more readable.  (At the time that I write this, the answer hasn't been edited yet.)

Comment: Upvoting: This answer was much clearer than the other answer, which doesn't even mention LAN/WAN ports for starters...